# Finding first and follow in a grammar

Tags: parsing

```
S->(L)|a  
L->SL'  
L'->,SL'|ε
```

I have to find the follow of the variables for the above grammar and I got the following answer:

```
Follow(S)={$, ',', ')'}  
Follow(L)= {')'}  
Follow(L')={')'}
```

But the answer is

```
Follow(S)={$, ',', ')'}  
Follow(L)= {')', $}  
Follow(L')={')', $}
```

The method I used is:
While finding follow of `L`, I looked for `L` in the right hand side of the productions.

In `S->(L)`, `follow(L)={')'}`

And `L` doesn't appear anywhere else

So, how does `follow(L)` contain `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of the follow sets of `L` and `L'` is correct, so the answer you cite is either incorrect or applies to some other grammar.